# Self-orthogonal states in Quantum Theory, 2

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement

This is my second try on the same question -- see [Self-orthogonal states in Quantum Theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/334910/self-orthogonal-states-in-quantum-theory). 
Suppose one considers a hypothetical "non-classical Quantum Theory": we work in a Hilbert-like space $k^n$ ($k$ some field) with Hermitian form $\langle \cdot \vert\cdot \rangle$, which is not necessarily an inner product, etc. The nonzero vectors in $k^n$ correspond to states. What would be the physical meaning of states $\vert \psi \rangle$ for which $\langle \psi \vert \psi \rangle = 0$, that is, *self-orthogonal states* ?

Comment: This would imply that, given a system in state $|\psi\rangle$, there is no possibility that it is in the state $|\psi\rangle$. By allowing this type of product you, quite clearly, lose whatever physical meaning quantum mechanics has.

Comment: [Related answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/160901/do-we-need-an-orthonormal-basis-in-quantum-mechanics/160908#160908)

Comment: In a physical theory, there are no such states - why do you expect them to have a physical meaning? (You might be coming from Gupta-Bleuler quantisation of QED, here we have to use virtual self-orthogonal photon states in our calculation. However, the actual Hilbert space is a quotient space where these states are removed.)

Comment: @ Noiralef: How is this quotient space formally defined ?

Comment: @BySymmetry: so as I understand it, there is no possibility that we will find the system in the same state $\vert \psi \rangle$ after some measurement. Couldn't such states have some "singular meaning" ?